# Sympy trying to solve ODE with boundary conditions

Tags: sympy

I am trying to solve the following ODE with boundary conditions. While I seem to be getting a solution, I do not understand why the solution doesn't reproduce the boundaries when I substitute the boundary conditions. I also want to generate a plot of x vs the solution, but the exact solution looks like a mathematical expression. Is there any way to get a real number as a solution?

Thanks!

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+3\frac{dy}{dx}+2y=4x^2, y(1)=1, y(2)=6$$

```
x = sp.Symbol('x')
u = sp.Function('u')(x)
eq = sp.Eq(u.diff(x,x) + 3 * u.diff(x) + 2 * u, 4 * x**2)
exact = sp.dsolve(eq, ics = {u.subs(x,1):1, u.subs(x,2):6})
print(f'exact:{exact.subs(x,1)}')
print(f'lhs: {exact.lhs}')
print(f'rhs: {exact.rhs.subs({x:1.0})}') # trying to reproduce boundary
------
exact:Eq(u(1), (-3*exp(4) - 2*exp(3))*exp(-2)/(-1 + E) + 3 + (2*E + 
3*exp(3))*exp(-1)/(-1 + E))

lhs: u(x)

rhs: 0.135335283236613*(-3*exp(4) - 2*exp(3))/(-1 + E) + 3.0 + 0.367879441171442*(2*E + 
3*exp(3))/(-1 + E) # why this long expression instead of 1.0
```